# Opencv VideoCapture not streaming RTSP link and returns "no frame!"

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, rtsp, hikvision

I am trying to stream my HikVision IP camera throough python. I am using `cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp_link")` which works fine on my Laptop but when I try to run the same python script with same Opencv and FFmpeg version it gives me following error:

**Error:**

```
[h264 @ 000002124c7f9a40] missing picture in access unit with size 47
[h264 @ 000002124c7f9a40] no frame!
```

I have so far tried to run this script on 5 computer devices but it gives the same error. I am using the following python script and my Opencv version is `4.6.0.66` and ffmpeg version `2022-06-20-git-56419428a8-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev`:

**Python Script:**

```
import cv2

# RTSP stream URL
rtsp_url = "rtsp://username:password@ip_address:port/Streaming/Channels/501"

# Open the RTSP stream
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(rtsp_url)

# Check if the stream was successfully opened
if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Failed to open RTSP stream.")
    exit()

# Read and display frames from the stream
while True:
    # Read a frame from the stream
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Check if the frame was successfully read
    if not ret:
        print("Failed to read frame from RTSP stream.")
        break

    # Display the frame
    cv2.imshow("RTSP Stream", frame)

    # Exit if 'q' is pressed
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# Release the resources
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Update:**

Code runs on a laptop on both wifi and mobile internet (4G) but on other devices rtsp link is accessible only with mobile internet (4G).